# Detect if app is really playing something or is silence

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I need to determine how much sound is really coming out from specific application as a number from **terminal**. (this is called silence in `pavucontrol`) I don't want to detect application current volume or if it's state is running.

I can see what I need in `PulseAudio volume control`. For example now both firefox and spotify are running but spotify is not silence.

[image]

I just want to detect the same thing in terminal if possible.

Thanks in advance.